# AttachmentsField Object Causes Error

Tags: data-view-web-part, attachments

I'm trying to display download links for files attached to list items in my DVWP.

The below code was working fine until I switched to (by switching I mean, deleting and creating a new web part) Linked Source.

```
<xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
    <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="ItemId"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Now the page gives me the following error:

*Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AttachmentsField' does not have a public property named 'xmlns:SharePoint'.*

Every list in the Linked Data Source is almost identical.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the problem you are having based on your description:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953271

What version number are you currently running?